# How to only use specific batches of data with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train a pix2pix network on Google Colab using Tensorflow 2.0 and I am using the tf.data.Dataset in order to import the data which are images (about 4900 total). However, since that's a lot of images to train with I have split the dataset into batches using the .batch() function. However, I am not aware of the way to use only one of the batches at a time when training so as not to have to load the whole dataset into RAM. In general, I am following the code here https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/pix2pix

When I pass the whole dataset in my train function to iterate over, RAM goes crazy and sometimes the whole notebook crashes. I am not sure how to only pass a random batch for each epoch to solve this problem.

This is how I load my data. In the end, each of the batches has shape (64,256,256,3).

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(workpath + '/train/*.jpg')


train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(4900, seed=23).take(4900)

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train,
                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(64)
```

My train function looks like the following.

```py
def train(dataset, epochs):

  for epoch in range(epochs):    
    for input_image, target in dataset:
      gen, disc = train_step(input_image, target)
          print('Gen loss: {} Disc loss: {}'.format(gen, disc))

train(train_dataset, 60)
```

If I pass the whole train_dataset in the train function it will loop over all batches in every epoch. I am trying to figure out a way to only pass a different batch in for each epoch. The only way I can think of doing that is if I reshuffle the batches and pick one out from the whole dataset for every epoch but that does not really solve the memory problem since I still have to pass the whole dataset in. Is there a quicker way to do this?